# How does the shell expose the services of the operating system to another program?

Tags: command-line

I was doing research on shell and found this written in [Shell (computing) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing))

> In computing, a shell is a computer program which exposes an operating system's services to a human user or other program.

What does *"other program"* mean here? I understand that it acts as an interface between human and operating system, but I don't understand the "other programs" part.

I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: If the shell is GNOME-Shell, the program maybe a calculator, editor etc. that performs a specific function for the user (user-program) that was started by the shell, and calls on the shell to perform functions. If using BASH, it maybe `bc` used for the same purposes just using the command line interface instead of GUI in the first example.  I don't see a connection though to anything on-topic here (it's a general OS question, and not Ubuntu or *flavor* of Ubuntu related, at least in my view) https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: How is this question related to Ubuntu? What "shell" are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

A shell is not a specific program. There are many different shells. Some shells are grpahical others are text based. GNOME, KDE and others are graphical shells that expose the file system, networking, bluetooth and applications to the user. The file system is the service provided by the operating system.

Some Text based shells are bash, fish, zsh. These expose the same services like file system, networking, bluetooth in a text interface. If you open bash using terminal app on Ubuntu. You can access the file system using the `ls` command to see all files. Use `cd <dir_name>` to access another folder/dir.

It exposes functionality to other programs in the sense that text shells  allow you to write commands in a file and execute  it. Hence they are exposing os functionality eg. files to that program that is your script.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal type `set` and you will see:

```
BASH=/bin/bash
BASHOPTS=checkwinsize:cmdhist:complete_fullquote:expand_aliases:extglob:extquote:force_fignore:histappend:interactive_comments:progcomp:promptvars:sourcepath
BASH_ALIASES=()
BASH_ARGC=()
BASH_ARGV=()
BASH_CMDS=()
BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR=/etc/bash_completion.d
BASH_LINENO=()
BASH_SOURCE=()
BASH_VERSINFO=([0]="4" [1]="3" [2]="48" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="x86_64-pc-linux-gnu")
BASH_VERSION='4.3.48(1)-release'
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
COLUMNS=92
COMPIZ_CONFIG_PROFILE=ubuntu
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-z04Udzqwi8
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db
DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=10c167c524c0620a1160872439246457700000025900001
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
DIRSTACK=()
DISPLAY=:0
```

This is some of the information the shell will give other programs that users rarely see. Some programs will behave differently depending on the information available here.